# PagerAdapter Give heap size when i inflate layout in this in android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I am inflating the linearlayout and creating view in viewpager but when i create this view it gives heap size i dont understand where i am wrong .i am loading image using picassa library in this 3 views; so inflating layout in constructor it gives heap memory ?

```
private ViewPager awesomePager;
    private static int NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS = 3;
    private AwesomePagerAdapter awesomeAdapter;

    ImageView mImageview;
    ImageView lImageview;
    ImageView rImageview;

    private View mLeft;
    private View mRight;
    private View mMiddle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);
        this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        awesomePager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.awesomepager);
        awesomeAdapter = new AwesomePagerAdapter(awesomePager,this);
        awesomePager.setAdapter(awesomeAdapter);
        awesomePager.setCurrentItem(1);
        awesomePager.setOnPageChangeListener(awesomeAdapter);
        awesomePager.setPageMargin(20);
   }

private class AwesomePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public AwesomePagerAdapter(ViewPager p,Context context) {
            super();
            inflater= (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mLeft=inflater.inflate(R.layout.leftcustom_imagevideo,null);
            mMiddle=inflater.inflate(R.layout.leftcustom_imagevideo,null);
            mRight=inflater.inflate(R.layout.leftcustom_imagevideo,null);
            p.addView(mLeft);
            p.addView(mMiddle);
            p.addView(mRight);
            lImageview=(ImageView)mLeft.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            mImageview=(ImageView)mMiddle.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            rImageview=(ImageView)mRight.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }


        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                awesomePager.setCurrentItem(1, false);

                pagechange=false;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS;
        }


        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    return mLeft;
                } else if (position == 1) {
                    return mMiddle;
                } else {
                    return mRight;
                }
        }        

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view==(object);
        }

    }
```

> Loading Image

```
private void nextImage(String tpath,int position) 
    {
        try 
        {

            DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            int imageWidth = (int) ( (float) metrics.widthPixels / 1.5 );
            int imageHeight = (int) ( (float) metrics.heightPixels / 1.5 );

            tpath=tpath.replaceAll(" ", "\\ ");

            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(tpath));

            if(position==0){
                lImageview.setImageDrawable(null);
                Picasso.with(DemoNewActivity.this).load(uri)
                .resize(imageWidth,imageHeight).config(Config.RGB_565).into(lImageview);
            }
            else if(position==1){

                mImageview.setImageDrawable(null);
                Picasso.with(DemoNewActivity.this).load(uri)
                .resize(imageWidth,imageHeight).config(Config.RGB_565).into(mImageview);                    
            }
            else if(position==2){

                rImageview.setImageDrawable(null);
                Picasso.with(DemoNewActivity.this).load(uri)
                .resize(imageWidth,imageHeight).config(Config.RGB_565).into(rImageview);
            }

        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {           
           e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you post some logcat snippets from the time the heap gets full? Something goes wrong when loading your pictures.

Comment: Logcat  http://pastie.org/9687515

Comment: i put how i loading the image i pass the path in imageview

Comment: Are handling large images? You may have to do some image transformation via Picasso, handling large bitmaps will quickly run out your heap.

Comment: yes i used large size images i download the image from server to sdcard for offline display after that i get image from sdcard and display image in imageview

Comment: Okey, I see, you have two options here, either you do server-side picture resampling or you handle in your app, of course this is a wider decision you have to take. Regardless, at least you know what the problem is, you need to handle your OutOfMemory exception. If Picasso cannot do it, then check out this link: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html